# Web-browser which runs fully in memory, without writing down any temporary files

Tags: web-browser

I am looking for the web browser which I can be setup to work fully in memory (since I've got 16GB of RAM). So no any temporary files should be created, but everything should be done in memory. Once quit, it should not leave any temporary folders or files. Something like `links -g`, but more modern web-browser.

The reason I'm looking for it, because my main SSD corrupting any stored files, so when I'm using Chrome or Firefox, the browsers are freezing all the time when any temporary files are created or accessed. Another use case could be when you're working on a read-only storage (e.g. booted live system from DVD).

The web-browser should be compatible with macOS or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Firejail (https://firejail.wordpress.com/) allows to run Firefox in a sandbox by restricting its views of the filesystem, and you could add a ramdisk, copy your profile to there at beginning, then launch Firefox with Firejail and at the end copy back the profile from ramdisk to disk, otherwise you loose many things.

It should be possible to do the same things with any other browser.